# How to prevent certain messages from being redelivered?

Tags: java, spring, error-handling, jms, spring-jms

I'm using Spring's `@JmsListener` to receive my messages from a queue:

```
@JmsListener(destination = "my-destination", containerFactory = "my-container-factory")
void receive(MyClass myObject) {
...
}
```

Also, the `containerFactory` has `sesstionTransacted` to `true`.

If the listener method throws an exception, then the transaction is rolled back and the message is redelivered, which is great. However, there are certain cases where I would not like the message to be redelivered, particularly when the incoming `JSON` message payload cannot be mapped to `MyClass`. This mapping happens implicitly by Spring before the above method is called, so I can't just wrap it in a `try-catch`. Is there any way to accomplish this (besides number 2 below)?

I tried:

1. Registering an `Errorhandler` with the `ContainerFactory` that does not rethrow. This does not prevent the transaction from being rolled back.
2. Changing the signature of the listener method to accept `TextMessage` and then doing the mapping myself, wrapping the mapping in a `try-catch`. This works, but I since it's not the most elegant solution I was wondering if there is any other way.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to to react to a JSON mapping error, I suggest to register a [HttpMessageConverterBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageConverter.html) which handles this case.